# Actionscript - making concurrent Loader load calls

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, concurrency

I upload a large file using [URLLoader.load](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#load%28%29) method. I use same load method (different Loader object) for other operations like opening a document. The problem comes when I'm uploading a large file and then try to open another a document operation. I look at network monitor and I see that call for open operation is queued in the network and it is not performed until the upload call finishes.

Is there a way to concurrently make `load` calls where one load operation doesn't block another?

**Update** I'm looking into using [workers (running in background)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html) for upload operations.

Comment: Why not wait before loading a new file? `loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loader_complete);`

Comment: Because then user can't make any other operations until upload is complete. Basically locking user from doing anything else. User should be able to upload a file and also perform "open" or "save" operations.

Comment: Does this also happen with different `Loader` instances?

Comment: Yes. I'm instantiating new Loader object for each call.